# Enable a button based on a value in the NSTableview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsbutton

I have a NSTableview. I need to enable the button based on a value of a column in the tableview. For instance, In the table view i have a column, Status. I have 2 kinds of status, Withdrawn and Booked. If i click on a row which has the status as Withdrawn, i need to disable the withdraw button. 
Can i be able to do it through binding? How could i do it? Pls help me out. Thanks.

Comment: For clarification, is the button in question located outside the table view, or is it located in the (view-based) table view as one of the column's table view cell? Is this a cell-based or view-based `NSTableView`? Are you currently supplying the values to the table view by bindings to an `NSArrayController`? What kind of value is `status` (for example, `NSString`, an enumerated type, `NSNumber`, etc.)?

Comment: Button is located outside the table view. It is view-based. I'm supplying the datas to table view by bindings to an NSArrayController. Status is of type NSString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you create a custom `NSValueTransformer`, you can enable or disable the button using bindings.

You can bind the `Enabled` property of the button as follows:

Bind to: `arrayController`

Controller Key: `selection`

Model Key Path: `status`

Value Transformer: `MDStatusValueTransformer`

NOTE: in place of `arrayController`, you should select whatever the name of your array controller is in the nib file. In place of `MDStatusValueTransformer`, you should specify whatever class name you end up naming the class I've provided below.

As I mentioned, you'll need to create a custom `NSValueTransformer`. The enabled property expects a `BOOL` wrapped in an `NSNumber`, but your `status` property is an `NSString`. So, you'll create a custom `NSValueTransformer` that will examine the incoming `status` `NSString`, and return `NO` if `status` is equal to `@"Withdrawn"`.

The custom `NSValueTransformer` should look something like this:

MDStatusValueTransformer.h:

```
@interface MDStatusValueTransformer : NSValueTransformer

@end
```

MDStatusValueTransformer.m:

```
@implementation MDStatusValueTransformer

+ (Class)transformedValueClass {
    return [NSNumber class];
}

+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation {
    return NO;
}

- (id)transformedValue:(id)value {
    if (value == nil) return nil;
    if (![value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) return nil;

    if ([value isEqualToString:@"Withdrawn"]) {
         return [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
    }
    return [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: @user1999892: You mean is there a way to do it without having to specify and write a custom value transformer?